# How do I convert a decimal number to a hex string in Perl?

Tags: perl, string, hex

How do I convert a decimal number to a hex string in Perl?

For example, I would like to convert `2001` into "0x07" and "0xD1".

Comment: @Peter, I believe you just broke autor's intent with your edit. `"0x07", "0xD1"` that was here previously **is the correct C syntax** that author wants according to comment on answer. `"0x07" and "0xD1"` is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for that case:

```
($x,$y) = map { "0x$_" } 
          sprintf("%04X\n", 2001) =~ /(..)(..)/;
```

But I wonder what you're really trying to do.  If you're trying to get UTF-16, this isn't the way you want to do that.

If you're trying to figure out the layout of packed binary data, then you should be using `unpack`.  The "C4" format would work for a 4-byte integer.

```
$int = 2001;
$bint = pack("N", $int);
@octets = unpack("C4", $bint);
printf "%02X " x 4 . "\n", @octets;
# prints: 00 00 07 D1
```

For some purposes, you can use `printf`'s vector print feature:

```
printf "%v02X\n", pack("N", 2001);
# prints: 00.00.07.D1

printf "%v02X\n", 255.255.255.240;
# prints: FF.FF.FF.F0
```

Comment: This is quite good, could you please generalize it a bit
and not only for 2 bytes numbers.
I've changed ($x,$y) to @arr, what about the =~ /(..)(..)/?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exact format you want it in, but one way to convert to hex is:

```
sprintf("%x", 2001)
```

Comment: This not quite good for me. I need to convert each byte to hex string.

Comment: What you are trying to do is somewhat awkward. If you describe what you are trying to achieve at a higher level, an alternative strategy might occur to someone.

Comment: I need to fill in a struct in C.
therefore I need to be able to write a script that breaks each byte of
an int to hex string byte.

Comment: Are you trying to generate C code, or simply construct the bytes of a C struct? If it's the latter, then use `pack("S", 2001)`.

Comment: No, this will not output as "07D1". "%x" will output in lower case. Use "%X" for the correct uppercase.